# AWS CLI v2 does not pick environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, zsh, aws-cli, oh-my-zsh

I've installed AWS CLI v2 via conda (macOS):

```
~ ❯ conda list                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# packages in environment at /Users/opal/miniconda3/envs/whatever:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
awscliv2                  1.5.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h033912b_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37hf985489_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    11.1.0               habf9029_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h046ec9c_2    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h2e338ed_4    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
pip                       21.1.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.10          h7728216_100_cpython    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.1                  h05e3726_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py37hf985489_3    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.35.5               h44b9ce1_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               h0419947_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                haf1e3a3_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h7795811_1010    conda-forge
~ ❯ aws --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
1.5.0
AWS CLI v2 command: docker run -i --rm -v /Users/opal/.aws:/root/.aws -v /Users/opal:/aws amazon/aws-cli
aws-cli/2.2.3 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.10.25-linuxkit docker/x86_64.amzn.2 prompt/off
```

I've no environment variables set and when I run:

```
~ ❯ aws sts get-caller-identity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"
```

which is as expected.

The problem is that when I export either `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable or `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` or `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` pair it works exactly the same. The only option to make it work is to pass the profile name via `--profile` switch.

What's the problem? Actually it's very annoying. It seems as if AWS CLI was unable to pick the values from environment variables.

I've set it on ZSH with oh-my-zsh.

**EDIT**
As far as I see/understand this command is run in a aws-cli docker container to which environment variables are not passed.

Comment: So you are runing aws cli in a docker?

Comment: Nope, at least not on purpose. I guess that this is somehow implemented that way.

Comment: Your error says `docker run -i --rm -v /Users/opal/.aws:/root/.aws -v /Users/opal:/aws amazon/aws-cli`. This only sets  /Users/opal/.aws to be available in the docker, not any env variables..

Comment: Yes I see it, that's why I assume it is being run on docker. I just run regular aws cli commands like `aws sts get-caller-identity` and it executes correctly but does not read the envs. No idea what docker is doing here.

Comment: Maybe conda uses aws cli through docker.

Comment: Yes, this is the most probable explanation. Thanks!